# How To Update an Excel File From a Gridview Row in ASP.NET (C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I am attempting a simple program. When the user clicks the button, the value of TextBox1 is run against a stored proc, returning a Customer ID. That Customer ID is looked up in an Excel sheet. If found, the information for the corresponding row is bound to a Gridview. However, once this is done, I would like to write THAT row to the second sheet of the excel file the info was pulled from. The code is a bit messy, as I'm trying a few different things in the process.

Currently the Excel file is saved, but of course the row that is currently there, is overwritten, so there will always be just one row.

What is the cleanest, easiest way to update (or insert) the data from a Gridview (only holding one row) to a sheet on an Excel file? Basically, this will be done over and over (when a user inputs a number and clicks the event button) so rows in the second sheet (Sheet2) will continually be updated from the Gridview. Any help is appreciated. I apologize if this sounds/looks amateurish.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (TextBox1.Text != "")
        {

            DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;
            long numCardNumber;
            string strCardNumber; // Card number (stored as string)
            char[] MyChar = { ';', '?' }; // array with 2 char
            string customerID; //holds the customer ID returned by the stored proc CNBID
            int CustID = 0; //Customer_id returned from stored proc CNBID
            int incrementByOne; //Used to increment number of cards scanned Application level variable

            //Create local label and assign text -> Site.Master lblTimeStamp
            Label lblTimeStampLocal = (Label)Master.FindControl("lblTimeStamp");
            Label lblScannedLocal = (Label)Master.FindControl("lblScanned");

            //Cleanup input
            strCardNumber = TextBox1.Text.TrimEnd(MyChar); // Trims end
            strCardNumber = strCardNumber.TrimStart(MyChar); //Trims beginning

            lbliMAG.Text = strCardNumber;

            lblYourNumber.Visible = false; //if previously displayed, turns the label off


            try //try and convert the string to a number (if valid numerical characters
            {
                numCardNumber = Convert.ToInt64(strCardNumber);                                                         
            }
            catch (FormatException) // thrown if input characters are not valid numeric
            {
                lblYourNumber.Visible = true;
                GridView1.Visible = false;
                lblQualify.Visible = false;
                lblYourNumber.Text = "NOT A VALID CARD NUMBER!";
                TextBox1.Focus();
                return;
            }

            try //try and convert the string to a number (if valid numerical characters
            {

                string connectionInfo = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConn"]);
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionInfo);                   
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CNBID", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@iMAG", SqlDbType.Char, 18); //@iMAG parameter
                param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                param.Value = strCardNumber; //Sets the parameter to the value of the scanned card (after trimmed characters)

                try
                {                                      
                    CustID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //returns int to customerID if card # found
                }
                catch
                {
                    lblYourNumber.Visible = true;
                    GridView1.Visible = false;
                    lblQualify.Visible = false;
                    lblYourNumber.Text = "NOT A VALID CARD NUMBER!";
                    TextBox1.Focus();
                    return;
                }

                TextBox1.Text = ""; //resets TextBox1; 

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (FormatException) // thrown if input characters are not valid numeric
            {
                lblYourNumber.Visible = true;
                GridView1.Visible = false;
                lblQualify.Visible = false;
                lblYourNumber.Text = "NOT A VALID CARD NUMBER!";
                TextBox1.Focus();
                return;
            }

            //if (customerID != null)
            if (CustID != 0)
            {

                lblCustID.Text = Convert.ToString(CustID); //assigns customerID to stat label
            }
            else
            {
                lblYourNumber.Visible = true;
                GridView1.Visible = false;
                lblQualify.Visible = false;
                lblYourNumber.Text = "Customer Not Found!";
            }

            //string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xls"].ConnectionString;
            string Excel = Server.MapPath("App_Data\\CNB.xls");
            string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

            //txtReturn.Text = connString; (//shows the connection string

            // Create the connection object
            OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                // Open connection
                oledbConn.Open();

                // Create OleDbCommand object and select data from worksheet Sheet1
                string ExcelConn = "SELECT custid,first,last,addr1,addr2,city,state,zip FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE custid=" + CustID;

                OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(ExcelConn, oledbConn);

                // Create new OleDbDataAdapter
                OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(); //OleDbDataAdapter.SelectCommand

                oleda.SelectCommand = cmd2;

                // Create a DataSet which will hold the data extracted from the worksheet.
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                //DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                // Fill the DataSet from the data extracted from the worksheet.
                oleda.Fill(ds, "Processed Customer");

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
                {                       
                    // Bind the data to the GridView                    
                    lblCol1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName;
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName = " Customer ID ";
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].ColumnName = " First Name ";
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Columns[2].ColumnName = " Last Name ";
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Columns[3].ColumnName = " Address 1 ";
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Columns[4].ColumnName = " Address 2 ";
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Columns[5].ColumnName = " City ";
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Columns[6].ColumnName = " Province / State ";
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Columns[7].ColumnName = " Postal Code / Zip ";

                    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                    GridView1.DataBind();

                    GridView1.Visible = true; // SHows the GridView after it populates
                    lblQualify.Visible = true;
                    lblQualify.Text = "Customer Qualifies!";
                    TextBox1.Focus();

                    incrementByOne = (int)Application["numberofTimesScanned"] + 1;
                    Application["numberofTimesScanned"] = incrementByOne;

                    lblTimeStampLocal.Text = "Last Scan: " + Convert.ToString(saveNow);
                    lblScannedLocal.Text = "Number Of Scans Completed: " + Convert.ToString(Application["numberofTimesScanned"]);


                    // Saves Excel document
                    var wb = new XLWorkbook();                    
                    wb.Worksheets.Add(ds);
                    wb.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("App_Data\\CustomersProcessed.xlsx"));

                    TextBox1.Focus();

                    try
                    {
                        cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Sheet2$] (CustID, FirstName) VALUES ('1123', 'Homer')", oledbConn);                            
                        oleda.InsertCommand = cmd2;
                    }
                    catch (Exception error)
                    {
                        lblYourNumber.Text = error.Message;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    lblQualify.Text = "Customer Does Not Qualify!";
                    GridView1.Visible = false; // Hides the Gridview 
                    TextBox1.Focus();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                lblYourNumber.Visible = true;
                GridView1.Visible = false;
                lblQualify.Visible = false;
                lblYourNumber.Text = error.Message;

            }
            finally
            {
                // Close connection
                oledbConn.Close();
            }

        } //END IF
        else
        {
            lblYourNumber.Visible = true;
            lblYourNumber.Text = "NO CARD NUMBER SUBMITTED!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your excel have to be in .xls format? It's much easier to manipulate .xlsx files there are several nice .net libraries.

Comment: No, it can be .xlsx format, absolutely. That's a good point, thanks Emmanuel.

Comment: Try [Epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), a nice libary to read and write .xlsx files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using the following:

```
using (DbCommand command = oledbConn.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Sheet2$] (custid, Fullname, Salutation) VALUES (" + CustID + ",\"John Smith\",\"John\")";

    //connection.Open();

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

That did the trick. :-)