# Extract Selected Row from GridView to Excel Sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have the following gridview, I want to add column as image icon to extract the selected row to Excel sheet. What is the code behined on image onclick event.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SuppliersPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApp_UNICEF.SuppliersPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


<asp:GridView ID="grdMain" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" 
    AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="grdMain_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    BorderColor="#1EA4DA" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellSpacing="2" onrowdatabound="grdMain_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" onpageindexchanging="grdMain_PageIndexChanging" 
    onrowcreated="grdMain_RowCreated" 
    >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />

    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" BorderColor="#19A5D9" BorderStyle="Solid" 
        BorderWidth="1px" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" BorderStyle="Solid" 
        BorderWidth="1px" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I would assume you have to do something like this:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961269/how-to-update-an-excel-file-from-a-gridview-row-in-asp-net-c?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ButtonField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Column for the displaying the image and having the functionality of click.

1. Add column of type `<asp:ButtonField>` in Columns collection of `GridView`.
2. Define the url of the image in `ImageUrl` property of the `ButtonField` defined in Step1.
3. Define the `CommandName` for the `ButtonField` defined in Step1, any name would work, for e.g. ExportToExcel

   4. Process the code for Exporting the row to excel in RowCommand Event of GridView.

void grdMain_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {

```
// CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
if(e.CommandName=="ExportToExcel")
{
  // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
  // property to an Integer.
  int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

// Rest of your code goes here to export to excel

}

//
// MarkUpCode
//
 <asp:ButtonField  CommandName="ExportToExcel" DataTextField="string"  DataTextFormatString="string" HeaderText="string" ImageUrl="uriOfImage" ShowHeader="True|False" SortExpression="string" Text = "Export"> </asp:ButtonField>
```

Comment: Thank u man, but when I add new column the headers doesnt change can u help me since it AutoGenerateColumn is true

Comment: In addition, can u please help me with the rest of code of excel to export since i cant find any thing related.